# How to change root directory for lamp on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, web, server

I'm trying to change the root directory of my new lamp on Ubuntu but I have an error message when I open localhost or 127.0.0.1 : **Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.**

I'm using Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80 with Ubuntu 21.04.

I already changed apache2.conf and 000-default.conf :

000-default.conf:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/matt/phpRoot
        ServerName 127.0.0.1


        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And apache2.conf :

```sh
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/matt/phpRoot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Comment: Put your LogLevel to debug, or even trace8 to see more details in your logs.  On top of allowing Apache access to /home/matt/phpRoot, the user that runs your Apache instance must have access to that directory at the linux level as well.  Configure permissions (and SELinux, if it is enabled).  Lastly, add `ServerAlias localhost` in your VirtualHost.

Answer (score 0):

in 000-default.conf and apache2.conf

change **/home/matt/phpRoot** to **/var/www**